# Are there recommendations to use "Hubble-Lemaître constant" instead of "Hubble constant"?

Tags: history, terminology, hubble-constant, iau

The IAU recommends renaming the Hubble *law* as the Hubble-Lemaître law, as discussed at its General Assembly in 2018 (see this [press release](https://www.iau.org/news/pressreleases/detail/iau1812/) and the links therein).

I have now stumbled upon an occurrence of "Hubble-Lemaître *constant*". Are there any recommendations (or noteworthy statements, opinion papers) in favor or against this extended interpretation of the IAU resolution B4 to the terminology for $H_0$?

Comment: To the question "Is the IAU recommending that any other “Hubble”-named things change?", the resolution committee just answers "No" (see the provided background information linked from the IAU press release).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, only the Hubble law was recommended to have its name changed (I'm a member of the IAU, so hopefully I'd have known if there were more votings).

However, several astronomers (including myself) found the voting a bit… weird; while acknowledging the work of George Lemaître is admirable, many more people than him and Edwin Hubble contributed to the understanding that the Universe is expanding. So, [some](https://twitter.com/anisotropela/status/1057200200069140480) were joking that we should rename the Law to the [Slipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vesto_Slipher)-[Friedmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Friedmann)-[Wirtz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Wilhelm_Wirtz)-[Lundmark](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knut_Lundmark)-[Lemaître](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges_Lema%C3%AEtre)-[Robertson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howard_P._Robertson)-[Hubble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_Hubble)-[de Sitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willem_de_Sitter)-[Humason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milton_L._Humason) law, or something like that.

Others joked that if the Hubble law should be renamed, we should also start referring to "the Hubble-Lemaître Space Telescope", "the Hubble-Lemaître Ultra Deep Field", "the Hubble-Lemaître Bubble", and, as you have seen, "the Hubble-Lemaître constant". Others probably also did this non-jokingly.

Btw., astronomer [Virginia Trimble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virginia_Louise_Trimble) wrote a paper six years ago ([Trimble 2013](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.2289)), arguing that we should name the Law after anybody but Hubble…

Comment: Good to see that the renaming doesn't violate [Stigler's law of eponymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler's_law_of_eponymy)...